# Format and echo datetime string received from MySQL?

Tags: php

how would I format a datetime string received from MySQL? For example, when I do

```
echo $info['start_datetime']
```

I get *2012-03-18 21:00:00*, but I would like to Turn it into Sunday, March 18, 2012. I looked at the php documentation where it showed the different formats, but not specifically when they're retrieved from MySQL.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hey I am currently using this for my script, how did you insert the date and time into your database? what function did you use **NOW()**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo date('l, F d, Y', strtotime($info['start_datetime']));
```

Comment: (or j instead of d if you do not want leading zeros)

Answer (score 3):

There are load of ways you can format the date. First change the time into timestamp using strtotime() function.

Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) page to get the list of how to format a date.

The usage is something like this

```
$time = strtotime($info['start_datetime']);
echo date("l, F d, Y", $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
echo ( date( "r", strtotime($info['start_datetime']) ) );
```

More options here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php